# Split duplicated rows of matrices in lists with base R

Tags: r, matrix, duplicates

I have a list of matrices, with duplicated values in column `id`. How can I split the duplicates in all list elements?

The way I do it with `data.frames` is with `lapply` + `split` + `duplicated`, but that doesnt work with matrices, as they are also split up in numerics. I would like to keep the matrix structure.

```
## Data.frame - all good
df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:10, each = 2),
  val = rep(10, each = 20)
)
df_list <- rep(list(df), 2);
lapply(df_list, function(x){split(x, duplicated(x[,'id']))$'FALSE'})

## Matrix - Here's my problem
mt <- as.matrix(data.frame(
  id = rep(seq(1,10,1), each = 2),
  val = rep(10, each = 20)
))
mt_list <- rep(list(mt), 2)
lapply(mt_list, function(x){split(x, duplicated(x[,'id']))$'FALSE'})
```

Comment: wrap the function in `matrix()` ? like `matrix(split(x, duplicated(x[,'id']))$'FALSE', ncol = 2)`

Comment: will `lapply( mt_list, unique )` suffice?

Comment: Correct, that also works. I still prefer the `subset.matrix` solution, as it keeps the column names.

Comment: 'unique' works in this simple case, but it wont with multiple columns with non-duplicated values. I maybe should have picked a better example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing that question and fiddling around with the code, I came up with a solution.
Since i didnt find anything about this specific setup, I though I'll post it anyway.

The functions `subset` / `subset.matrix` work:

```
lapply(mt_list, function(x){subset.matrix(x, !duplicated(x[,'id']))})
```

I benchmarked the different options; `subset.matrix` seems to be slightly faster than just `subset`.

```
 mt <- as.matrix(data.frame(
  id = rep(seq(1,1000,1), each = 2),
  val = rep(1000, each = 20)
))
mt_list <- rep(list(mt), 50)
mc <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  subset = lapply(mt_list, function(x){subset(x, !duplicated(x[,'id']))}),
  subset.matrix = lapply(mt_list, function(x){subset.matrix(x, !duplicated(x[,'id']))}),
  split = lapply(mt_list, function(x){matrix(split(x, duplicated(x[,'id']))$'FALSE', ncol = 2)}),
  unique = lapply( mt_list, unique )
)
mc
```

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>           expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
>         subset   3.758708   3.862849   4.256363   3.900580   3.981629   9.713416   100 a  
>  subset.matrix   3.583632   3.700450   4.174137   3.729881   3.821947   9.611992   100 a  
>          split  32.630604  33.061503  34.535531  33.262841  33.726039  77.531039   100  b 
>         unique 144.832487 148.408874 155.099591 150.326865 155.456601 430.992916   100   c
> ```

Comment: should only need to call `subset` I think. It will dispatch to `subset.matrix`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try

```
split(df,ave(df$id, df$id, FUN= function(x) seq_along(x)))
$`1`
   id val
1   1  10
3   2  10
5   3  10
7   4  10
9   5  10
11  6  10
13  7  10
15  8  10
17  9  10
19 10  10

$`2`
   id val
2   1  10
4   2  10
6   3  10
8   4  10
10  5  10
12  6  10
14  7  10
16  8  10
18  9  10
20 10  10
```

Comment: `ave` is defintily faster than the other options, but this solution only works on data.frames.

Comment: @SeGa how about `lapply( split(mt,ave(mt[,1], mt[,1], FUN= function(x) seq_along(x))),matrix,ncol=2)`

Comment: Although this works and is very fast, I actually dont think it's doing what I was looking for. For this simple example the result is the same, but it does actually split the duplicates of the matrices in lists, or? What I was looking for was how to remove duplicated rows in lists of matrices. Try out with `mt <- as.matrix(data.frame(
  id = rep(seq(1,10,1), each = 3),
  val = rep(10, each = 30)
))`

Comment: This one would work though, although it looses all its performance advantage: `lapply(mt_list, function(mt1) {mt1[ave(mt1[,1], mt1[,1], FUN = function(x) duplicated(x))==0,]})`